# Multi-derivative containing standard normal CDF

Tags: derivatives, normal-distribution, stochastic-calculus

I've got a question about the following multi-derivative
    $$\frac{\text{d}^m}{\text{d}a^m} \left(e^{-2\mu a}\Phi \left(\frac{a-\mu u}{\sqrt{u}}\right)\right),$$
where $m> 0$ is an integer , $\mu>0$, and $u>0$ are constants, $a>0$, $\Phi(x) $ is the standard normal CDF, and $\phi(x)$ is the standard normal PDF.

I tried to find
    $$\frac{\text{d}^m}{\text{d}x^m} \left(e^{bx}\Phi \left(x\right)\right),$$
firstly, but it seems be very difficult to get a recursive answer.

Any help or idea would be the most grateful.

---

I'm not sure whether the following derivative can be used,
    $$\frac{\text{d}^m}{\text{d}x^m}\Phi \left(x\right)=(-1)^{m-1}H_{m-1}(x)\phi(x),$$
where $H_m(x)$ is Hermite polynomial defined as
    $$H_m(x)=(-1)^m e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}\frac{\text{d}^m}{\text{d}x^m}\left(e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\right).$$

Answer (score 1):

By using $ e^{bx}\varphi(x) = e^{\frac{b^2}{2}}\varphi(x-b) $, we have

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&\frac{\text{d}^m}{\text{d}x^m} (e^{bx}\varphi(x)) \\
=& \frac{\text{d}^m}{\text{d}x^m} (e^{\frac{b^2}{2}}\varphi(x-b))\\
=& e^{\frac{b^2}{2}} \frac{\text{d}^m}{\text{d}x^m} (\varphi(x-b))\\
=& e^{\frac{b^2}{2}} (-1)^m H_m (x-b) \varphi(x-b).
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Therefore,

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
 \frac{\text{d}^m}{\text{d}x^m} \left(  e^{bx} \Phi(x) \right)=& b^m e^{bx} \Phi(x) \\
 & + e^{\frac{b^2}{2}} \varphi(x-b) \Big[  b^{m-1} +(-1)^1 H_1 (x-b) b^{m-2} \\
 & +, \dotsc, +(-1)^{m-2} H_{m-2} (x-b)b +(-1)^{m-1} H_{m-1} (x-b)  \Big] ,
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where $H_m(x)$ is Hermite polynomial defined as above.